# how to change time tick step in d3.js?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

Can't make **5 min step** in my chart.

This is the part of an object that I pass to `Angular Material` Chart directive
This is my `xAxis`:

```js
xAxis: {
  tickFormat: function(d) {
    return $filter('date')(new Date(d * 1000), 'HH:mm');
  },
  ticks: 5, // as I know 2,5,10
  showMaxMin: false
},
```

My **X** time scale is ***17:46 / 18:03***
I've been trying to change different values, and also been reading D3 Tips & Trick but didn't find the answer.

I want to make a **5 min step**, that my X scale looks like ***18:00 / 18:05 / 18:10***

Comment: Can you provide a full example as a Plunker/JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = data[0].x;
var finishDate = data[data.length - 1].x; 
chart.xAxis.tickValues(d3.time.minutes(startDate, finishDate, 5));
```

Essentially it uses d3.time.minutes to generate an array with timestamps every 5 minutes. This then gets passed to tickValues.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer, I didn't downvote you, but your solution don't work

Comment: Ah yes because nvd3 doesn't pass through the second parameter. 

This works instead:
   
        var startDate = data[0].x;
        var finishDate = data[data.length - 1].x;
        viewFinder.xAxis.tickValues(d3.time.minutes(startDate, finishDate, 5));

Essentially it uses d3.time.minutes to generate an array with timestamps every 5 minutes. This then gets passed to tickValues.